# 'skipping' a table in SQL inner joins

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

What I mean is, If I had the following schema:

```
create table tableA(
    A_id   number not null primary key
);

create table tableB(
    B_id   number not null primary key,
    A_id   number not null references tableA(A_id),
    B_data text   not null
);

create table tableC(
    C_id   number not null primary key,
    A_id   number not null references tableA(A_id),
    C_data text   not null
);
```

If I wanted to retrieve `B_data` and `C_data` using the relationships described here, is there any difference between the following:

```
select
    b.B_data,
    c.C_data
from
    tableB b
    inner join tableC c
        on b.A_id = c.A_id;
```

and:

```
select
    b.B_data,
    c.C_data
from
    tableB b
    inner join tableA a
        on b.A_id = a.A_id
    inner join tableC c
        on a.A_id = c.A_id;
```

I suspect that most databases will optimise either query to be the same, but are there cases where the foreign key constraints to `tableA` will make joining via `tableA` much more efficient? Are there any cases where these queries could produce different results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may as well join them directly.  Foreign key constraints don't do anything to make joins more efficient; indexes do that, which (depending on DBMS) may be a separate matter from foreign keys.  Either way, if there's an index to work with, you have it regardless of whether you're going by your foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

The first version works fine. Foreign key relationships are about referential integrity and don't necessarily have to be traversed as they are defined.